# unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing! - android device

Tags: android

I'm trying to install my apk (which uses google maps) in android device. Its not getting installed. when i collect the log from the device it shows "unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!"

how to solve the above problem.?

I have given following line inside application tag.

```
<uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps"
            android:required="true" >
        </uses-library>
```

Following is my logs

```
 02-03 20:19:42.025 D/PackageManager( 2888): Scanning package com.test.sd.view
02-03 20:19:42.025 E/PackageManager( 2888): Package com.test.sd.view requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!
02-03 20:19:42.025 W/PackageManager( 2888): Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.test.sd.view.apk
02-03 20:19:42.085 D/dalvikvm( 2888): GC_EXPLICIT freed 823K, 60% free 15109K/36871K, paused 2ms+5ms
02-03 20:19:42.085 D/InstallAppProgress( 4485): Installation error code: -9
```

Comment: Are you trying it in the emulator or device?

Comment: device. samsung 7" tab. OS version is 2.3.4

Comment: no. i'm not using custom ROM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess it is an issue with the device. Refer http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/bbs/discussion/view.do?platformId=0&parentCategoryId=0&messageId=101074&boardId=10. Try loading maps library externally.

Answer (score 0):

In case with real device try remove from manifest file:

`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`